# Avoid Lambda expression with multiple where clause

Tags: c#, sql, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-4

How can we define multiple where clause in a single lambda expression. What I need, if lambda expression finds result with matching criteria then it filters out only those records otherwise it will return all records. I want to get this in a single lambda expression. As I have multiple criteria on which I have to filter records from database using lambda expression.

I don't want to use if else conditions and then change my lambda expression accordingly. I want to achieve this in a single expression.

```
var objList = from o in db.sometable
                              join p in db.sometable1 on o.sometable1Id equals p.Id
                              join q in db.sometable2 on p.Id equals q.Id
                              join r in db.sometable3 on p.Id equals r.Id
                              join s in db.sometable4 on o.id equals s.Id
                              where r.1stcriteria == X || r.2ndCriteria == Y || r.3rdCriteria == Z
                              select new
                              {
                                  o.Id,
                                  r.X,
                                  r.Y,
                                  s.Name,
                                  o.area_sold,
                                  p.stock

                              };
```

On above expression i need to get result even if no criteria match or any one of them matched.Or even two of them matched.

Comment: Do provide your expression with conditions.

Comment: "I need to get a result even if no criteria match or any one matched". Are you sure about this? as this would bring all results.

Comment: "On above expression i need to get result even if no criteria match or any one of them matched.Or even two of them matched." So you want to avoid the objList to be null, is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't fully understand, you can use multible criteria on where: list.where(x=> (condition1) || (condition2)). To get the whole list simply add one if afterwards:

```
var filteredList = myList.where(x=> (conditions1(x)) || (condition2(x))).toList();

if (filteredList.count == 0)
    filteredList = myList;
```

Answer (score 2):

In your lambda expression operator logic is still in play and will provide you with what you need if i understand what you want, say for instance we take this

```
.Where(a=> a.ID == someId);
```

Say this would be our one criteria, now in order to add a second you can add AND or OR logic to the mix using && and ||

```
.Where(a=> (a.ID == someId) && ((a.ID < 50) && (a.ID > 5)));
```

Parenthesis is important though if you would like to group your Boolean checks correctly.